# Can't save page status when navigating between pages

Tags: flutter

Whenever the user navigates to a different window the state of the previous window isn't preserved. How can I make it so that the code preserves the state of the page before navigating to a different page.

My code currently has two pages the user can navigate to, The main page which is the central hub of the program and the second page which is called "Check Inventory" When the user clicks the "Check Inventory" button in the main page the program brings the user to the "Check Inventory" window which initially displays 5 buttons all labeled 'Task #' the first button "Task 1" has a red dot next to it and is enabled by default. The other buttons are enabled when the user presses the button where the red dot is located. For example:Pressing the 'Task 1' button will move the red dot to the 'Task 2' button while at the same time enabling the 'Task 2' button. Repeat until the user reaches the 'Task 5' button.

When the user presses the 'Task 5' button the 'Return to previous page' button should show which allows the user to navigate back to the main page. How can I make it so that when the user presses the 'Return to previous page' button or during anytime the user navigates away from the second page it preserves the current state of 'Second page' so that when the user navigates back to the 'Second page' from the main page it doesn't reset the state of the second page back to when it was first navigated to?

Main page code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../Classes/provider_class.dart';// Import the provider class
import '../Classes/Button_Data.dart';
import 'second_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => PageProvider(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Button_Data> buttonsData = [
    Button_Data('Check Inventory', true),
    Button_Data('Sell and Collect', false),
    Button_Data('Distribute POSM', false),
    Button_Data('Remit Sales', false),
    Button_Data('Return and Restock', false),
    Button_Data('Get ending Inventory', false),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('EX Trucker Tasks'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: buttonsData.map((buttonData) => CustomButton(
            key: PageStorageKey<String>(buttonData.name),
            buttonData: buttonData,
            onTap: () {
              if (buttonData.name == 'Check Inventory') {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                );
              } else {
                print('Button ${buttonData.name} pressed!');
              }
            },
          )).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Button_Data buttonData;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  CustomButton({Key? key, required this.buttonData, required this.onTap})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: buttonData.isEnabled ? onTap : null,
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor:
          buttonData.isEnabled ? null : MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),
        ),
        child: Text(buttonData.name),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Second page code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../Classes/Button_Data.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../Classes/provider_class.dart'; // Import the provider class

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SecondPage> {
  late List<Button_Data> secondPageButtonsData;
  bool showReturnButton = false;

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeSecondPage();
  }

  bool isFirstLoad = true;

  Future<void> initializeSecondPage() async {
    PageProvider pageProvider = Provider.of<PageProvider>(context, listen: false);
    await loadStoredState();

    // Enable buttons up to the active index when the page is loaded for the first time
    if (isFirstLoad) {
      for (int i = 0; i < secondPageButtonsData.length; i++) {
        secondPageButtonsData[i].isEnabled = i <= pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex;
      }
      showReturnButton = pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex == secondPageButtonsData.length - 1;
      isFirstLoad = false;
    } else {
      // Enable all buttons when not the first load
      for (int i = 0; i < secondPageButtonsData.length; i++) {
        secondPageButtonsData[i].isEnabled = true;
      }

      // Check if 'Return to Previous Page' button should be shown
      showReturnButton = secondPageButtonsData.last.isEnabled;
    }
  }


  Future<void> loadStoredState() async {
    secondPageButtonsData = [
      Button_Data('Task 1', true),
      Button_Data('Task 2', false),
      Button_Data('Task 3', false),
      Button_Data('Task 4', false),
      Button_Data('Task 5', false),
    ];

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    for (int i = 0; i < secondPageButtonsData.length; i++) {
      Map<String, dynamic>? storedData = await retrieveStoredState(secondPageButtonsData[i].name);
      if (storedData != null) {
        secondPageButtonsData[i].isEnabled = storedData['isEnabled'] ?? false;
      }
    }

    showReturnButton = secondPageButtonsData.last.isEnabled;
  }

  void storeState(Button_Data buttonData) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('${buttonData.name}_isEnabled', buttonData.isEnabled);
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> retrieveStoredState(String buttonName) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool? isEnabled = prefs.getBool('${buttonName}_isEnabled');
    if (isEnabled != null) {
      return {'isEnabled': isEnabled};
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    PageProvider pageProvider = Provider.of<PageProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Check Inventory'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < secondPageButtonsData.length; i++)
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  if (i == pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex && !showReturnButton)
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                      width: 8.0,
                      height: 8.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  CustomButton(
                    buttonData: secondPageButtonsData[i],
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (i == pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex &&
                            i < secondPageButtonsData.length - 1) {
                          // Check if the correct button is pressed to increment the index
                          pageProvider.setSecondPageActiveButtonIndex(i + 1);
                          secondPageButtonsData[pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex].isEnabled = true;
                          storeState(secondPageButtonsData[pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex]);
                        } else if (i == secondPageButtonsData.length - 1) {
                          // Show 'Return to previous page' button when 'Task 5' is pressed
                          showReturnButton = true;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            if (showReturnButton)
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MainPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Text('Return to previous page'),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Button_Data class

```
class Button_Data {
  final String name;
  bool isEnabled;

  Button_Data(this.name, this.isEnabled);
}
```

Provider class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late int secondPageActiveButtonIndex = 0;

  //with this method you set the value in the provider
  void setSecondPageActiveButtonIndex(int value) {
    secondPageActiveButtonIndex = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Edited the post to update the status of the problem along with including an updated version of the code I'm using.

Ok so I'm using a provider class to save the state of my second page but it doesn't seem to load the second page a second time properly where when it loads the page a second time it just enables the 'Task 1' button but puts the red dot at the 'Task 5' button which is disabled. Clicking on the 'Task 1' button enables all the buttons and removes the red dot from them. I've isolated the logic error in a particular function since the second page functions normally when loaded for the first time.

the function in question

```
Future<void> initializeSecondPage() async {
    PageProvider pageProvider = Provider.of<PageProvider>(context, listen: false);
    await loadStoredState();

    // Enable buttons up to the active index when the page is loaded for the first time
    if (isFirstLoad) {
      for (int i = 0; i < secondPageButtonsData.length; i++) {
        secondPageButtonsData[i].isEnabled = i <= pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex;
      }
      showReturnButton = pageProvider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex == secondPageButtonsData.length - 1;
      isFirstLoad = false;
    } else {
      // Enable all buttons when not the first load
      for (int i = 0; i < secondPageButtonsData.length; i++) {
        secondPageButtonsData[i].isEnabled = true;
      }

      // Check if 'Return to Previous Page' button should be shown
      showReturnButton = secondPageButtonsData.last.isEnabled;
    }
  }
```

Comment: you need to use state management to preserve your page's state. meaning that the state is saved in some other class externally and when you re-open the page, it will fetch the page state that was previously left.

Comment: how do I do that? Sorry I'm still kinda new to how flutter handles variables when page to page navigation is concerned.

Comment: you can start with provider. Which is the best to start with, in my opinion. There are many videos already available on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a State management tool like Vivek Chib mentioned it in the comments. You can use something liek Provider or Riverpod.

You safe the data there and make them accessable in the whole app. You only have to call them in your application then. So everything you need to restore you put in the provider and call it for example in the build method and then set the values.

Everywhere you need to change the values you use a set function.

So something like this if you use Provider:

The Provider:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late int secondPageActiveButtonIndex = 0;
  
  //with this method you set the value in the provider
  void setSecondPageAciveButtonIndex(int value) {
    secondPageActiveButtonIndex = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

SecondPage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Classes/Button_Data.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'PageProvider.dart' //wherever you have stored the provider
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

  // int storedActiveButtonIndex = 0;
  // bool storedReturnButtonState = false;

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<SecondPage> {
  // int activeButtonIndex = 0;
  final List<Button_Data> secondPageButtonsData = [
    Button_Data('Task 1', true),
    Button_Data('Task 2', false),
    Button_Data('Task 3', false),
    Button_Data('Task 4', false),
    Button_Data('Task 5', false),
  ];

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    // you call the provider and then you just use provider.value and set it everywhere
    PageProvider pageProvider =
        Provider.of<PageProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Check Inventory'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < secondPageButtonsData.length; i++)
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  if (i == provider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex && !showReturnButton)
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                      width: 8.0,
                      height: 8.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  CustomButton(
                    buttonData: secondPageButtonsData[i],
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (i < secondPageButtonsData.length - 1 &&
                            provider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex == i) {
                          // Increment only when a 'Task' button (excluding 'Task 5') is pressed
                          provider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex++;
                          secondPageButtonsData[provider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex].isEnabled = true;
                          print(
                              'Button ${secondPageButtonsData[provider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex].name} pressed!');
                          print('Active Index: ${provider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex}');
                        } else if (i == secondPageButtonsData.length - 1) {
                          // Show 'Return to previous page' button when 'Task 5' is pressed
                          showReturnButton = true;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            if (showReturnButton)
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  // Store values before navigating
                  //storedActiveButtonIndex = provider.secondPageActiveButtonIndex;
                  storedReturnButtonState = showReturnButton;
                  pageProvider.setSecondPageAciveButtonIndex(value);
                  // Navigate to MainPage and wait for it to pop
                  await Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MainPage(),
                    ),
                  );

                  // Restore values when returning to SecondPage
                  setState(() {
                    activeButtonIndex = storedActiveButtonIndex;
                    showReturnButton = storedReturnButtonState;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Return to previous page'),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Initial post has been updated with the current state of the code I now have based on everyone's suggestions.